# using Init.ps1 to add item in the csproj file

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

i am using Nuget to install a package due to some restrictions i have to generate a reference and the path of the assembly in my `csproj` file.

i am think of doing it with `Init.ps1` file which runs when you first install the package.
the element that i want to add is the `Reference` element  some thing like.

and should be like

```
<Reference Include="Library.MyLib.Imaging, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\SDK.0.9.2\lib\wp8\X86\Library.mylib.Imaging.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Can some body guide me that how i can add these to the csproj file. i belive that `AddItem` method can be used from the `Project` Class

[project Class Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project_methods.aspx)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the false assumption you made for `init.ps1`: that PowerShell script is run **everytime the package is initialized (or every time the solution is loaded)** which is likely not what you want in this scenario. You'll have to use `install.ps1` instead, which is run once during installation of the package only.

The main issue with making changes to a consuming project file is that you'll have to know the file name somehow. The parameters that get injected into the PowerShell scripts are the following ones:

> param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

I've had a similar requirement and what I did instead of automating it during package installation: I expose a cmdlet in the Package Manager Console for the consumer to use.
You can find an example of my implementation on GitHub for the NuSpec package: https://github.com/myget/NuGetPackages/blob/master/NuSpec/tools/NuSpec.psm1

Maybe that will help you to get started. If you do have a proper solution to fully automate this during package installation, please feel free to share it here as well (or send me a Pull Request :-)).